# Materalize css: Email and Password label overlapping on browser auto fill

Tags: jquery, materialize

**I am using materalize css for login and signup form.On email and password field,
i have a overlapping problem in both signup and signin form.**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 21px;">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input  id="email" type="email" class="validate" name="user_login" 
         required="" autocomplete="off" >
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="autofill validate" 
        name="password" required="">
        <a  class="forgot" href="{"auth.recover_password"|fn_url}">Forgot?</a>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    M.updateTextFields();
});
```

output of code: https://prnt.sc/jmshv1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the materialize js file. Your code is working when the js file is included.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>`

jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/eof64tuh/

[image]

Comment: By including script,result remains same

Comment: I have attached screenshot of fiddle. do you see any errors in your console.

Comment: There is no error iin console. label is overlapping in case of browser autofill.i have edited the question please recheck